# The proof of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \Gamma(X_{an},\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, then it has a complex manifold structure, denoted by $X_{an}$. Then by Serre's theorem:

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, then there is an equivalence of categories from the category of coherent sheaves on $X$ to the category
of coherent analytic sheaves on $X_h$. Furthermore, for every coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, (recall every projective algebraic variety $X$, we can view it as an
analytic variety, denoted as $X_h$)  we have:
$$H^i(X,F)\cong H^i((X_h),F_h)$$

It follows that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}})$, where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the structure sheaf on variety $X$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}}$ is the structure sheaf on complex manifold.  My question is if there is an alternative way to see $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \Gamma(X_{an},\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}})$ without using Serre's theorem, or is this obvious to see $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \Gamma(X_{an},\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}})$?

Comment: Both sides are just the locally constant functions, so maybe there is not so much here. Why? Projective varieties are complete, and the analyticification of a complete variety is compact, and there are no non-locally constant functions on a compact variety by the maximum principle.

Comment: @KReiser I like the answer a lot, but why aren't they globally constant? A holomorphic function on a compact connected set is constant, so the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{X_{an}}$ are constant right?

Comment: @KReiser and why are the global regular functions locally constant?

Comment: For part 1, consider disconnected varieties: two points, for example (I don't require that variety imply irreducible). For part 2, this is a basic consequence of completeness - every image of a complete variety is again complete, every global function may be interpreted as a morphism to $\Bbb A^1$, and the only complete subvarieties of $\Bbb A^1$ are finite sets of points.